# Automatically click a button in WP plugin daily via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin and it's cache fills very quickly.  In order to empty the cache I can login and press a button via WP's backend.

I would like this to happen daily (no set time required), automatically to save me having to log in every day.

The HTML for the button looks like this:

```
<input style="float:right;" class="button-primary" value="Delete All" name="delete_all_links" id="delete_all_links" type="button">
```

and the jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery("input:button#delete_all_links").live("click",function(){
if(confirm("Click OK to delete all.")){
delete_all_url("All");
}
});

function delete_all_url(all){
  var data={
  action : "delete_all_url",
  is_auto: all
  };

  jQuery.post(ajaxurl,data,function(){
    jQuery("table#list_all_url > tbody > tr").animate({opacity:0},400,function(){
    //jQuery(this).remove();
    //update_pagination(curr_page);
    search_cloaked_links();
    });
  });
}
```

Is it possible to change the jquery so it does this automatically?

Comment: Without log in, there is no button to click. That would be a big security hole.

Comment: Why do you want to empty the cache anyway, it's there for a reason

Comment: That would be very useless. Like @alexP said, you have to login to click. To do that better, find the PHP function that button is executing and create a cron job to run daily with that function.

Comment: Thanks @yomisimie I'll look into that now..

Comment: if you want do something every day on the website, you should use cron jobs.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement a cron to execute the jquery function

Comment: Selenium may be an option here as well, if you are unable to get around not logging in.